# How to start another activity from webChromeClient

Tags: android, android-activity, webviewclient, webchromeclient

In webViewClient I use shouldOverrideUrlLoading to check a link/url and load another activity but how can I do the same trick in webChromeClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in a `webChromeClient`. You have to set both, `webViewClient` and `webChromeClient`.

Comment: Aha, so use webViewClient with Override will only intercept the call... Thanks. Would you be so kind to read my other question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664363/webchromeclient-opens-link-in-browser/14666722