# How to display a progress bar when WebView loads a URL, in Android ？

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

**I am new in android apps development and learning it.**

I have developed an application which loads a website link using a `WebView`. And it's working fine.

But I am facing problems to display and hide progress bar when the `WebView` loads a page.

I want to display a progress bar (Just spinner in center) when the WebView loads the main link and internal links of a website and hide progress bar when page is completely loaded.

My Java code:

```
package in.matebook.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.labnol.org");
    }



    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.labnol.org")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                //or we can add more allowed host in if condition
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my layout XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now, the progress bar is displayed, but it does not hide.

When I create **progressbar** object and add below line in Java code then the progress bar is not displayed.

```
progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I have also tried [an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375222/android-how-can-i-show-progress-bar-while-loading-data-to-webview) but the progress bar does not work when I click on internal links.

1. I want to display progress bar when main page load and hide progress bar when the main page is completely loaded.
2. I want to display the progress bar again when the user clicks on internal links of the website and same as above, hide the progress bar when the page is completely loaded.

Please help, I am beginner in Android apps development.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try this code... you need webChoromeClient to track the webview load progress...

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    if (progress == 100) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
 }
});
```

Replace your webview client with this code....

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have changed **setWebViewClient** to **setWebChromeClient** and Working BUT a new problem has created. When i use **@Override** before **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method. It says **method does not override from its suerclass** And i think so when i click on any link it prompt me to open using other apps. Please help

Comment: i take advantage of your and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664363/webchromeclient-opens-link-in-browser answer and solved this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is looking for a **Kotlin** solution, this simple one worked for me:

```
private fun setupWebView() {

    val webViewClient: WebViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            showProgressDialog()
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            hideProgressDialog()
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }
    }
    webView.webViewClient = webViewClient

    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Guaranteed Solution:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey guys, I have useful this method, That would surely help you too.**

XML

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Java:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webid);
WebSettings websettings = webView.getSettings();

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);


webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String url){
       ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
       progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**I've added following to my code and it worked very well for me.**

**XML:**

```
   <WebView
    android:id="@+id/updates_webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  />

   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**Java:**

```
public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        ProgressBar progressBar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```